# Javascript on YouTube Video Change

Tags: javascript, youtube

Okay, I'm a SQL programmer by trade but I'm trying to figure out a (supposedly) simple greasemonkey javascript, cobbled together from other examples many of which found here.

Basically, I want to check the current video user against an array of "good" users. If they are found in the list, no problem; if they aren't, then redirect the page back to youtube.com.  I have the script working on the first video play, but when another video is selected by link the document object doesn't seem to be loaded or the getElementByClassName doesn't find anything and returns "undefined".

Here is the full GreaseMonkey script thus far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube Limit To Users
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org/users/23652
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/watch
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

var goodYoutubers=["Sqaishey Quack", "Graser10", "Good Mythical Morning"]; 

window.onload = DoCheckForUser();

function youtubePageChange()
{
    DoCheckForUser();
    $('body').on('transitionend', function(event)
    {
    if (event.target.id != 'progress') return false;
    DoCheckForUser();
    });
}

$(youtubePageChange);

function DoCheckForUser () {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('yt-user-info');
  var aNode = y[0];  //<<< this goes "undefined"
  var currentUser = aNode.textContent.trim();
  alert(currentUser);

  var indexUser = goodYoutubers.indexOf(currentUser);
  if (indexUser < 0)
    {
      alert(currentUser + " is NOT an approved YouTuber!");
      window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
    }
  else
    {
      alert(currentUser + " is an approved YouTuber!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in background script:

```
window.addEventListener("spfdone", process); // old youtube design
window.addEventListener("yt-navigate-start", process); // new youtube design
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", process); // one-time early processing
window.addEventListener("load", process); // one-time late postprocessing
```